# Definition of (lazy) conditional in partial recursive functions

Tags: computability, recursion, partial-functions

I'm currently working on formalizing the theory of partial recursive functions, and something seems peculiar about the standard definition. The definition of the primitive recursion clause of $\mu$-recursive functions reads as follows (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function)):

> Given the $k$-ary function $g({\bf x})$ and $k+2$-ary function $h(y,z,{\bf x})$:
>   \begin{align}
>              \rho(g, h) &\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} f \quad\text{where}\\
>     f(0,{\bf x}) &= g({\bf x}) \\
>   f(y+1,{\bf x}) &= h(y,f(y,{\bf x}),{\bf x}).
> \end{align}

I assume that this definition uses *eager evaluation*, which is to say that $h(y,f(y,{\bf x}),{\bf x})$ is defined only when $f(y,{\bf x})$ is, even if when we evaluate $h$ it turns out to be a projection or otherwise ignores this argument.

Now this evaluation order means that if $f(y,{\bf x})=\bot$ then $f(y+1,{\bf x})=\bot$. But now how can I define a conditional operator like so:

$$\mathrm{ifz}(g,h)(x)\simeq g(x)\quad\mbox{if }x=0$$
$$\mathrm{ifz}(g,h)(x)\simeq h(x)\quad\mbox{if }x\ne 0$$

where $a\simeq b$ means that both sides are undefined, or defined and equal? Without worrying about definedness, $\mathrm{ifz}$ is a trivial application of primitive recursion, but the naive definition will have $\mathrm{ifz}(\bot,0)(1)=\bot$ since it first tries to evaluate the zero branch. Since obviously Turing machines can define an $\mathrm{ifz}$ operator, either my definition is wrong or there is a more clever way to construct it.

Related (but also unanswered): [Eager vs. lazy interpretation of recursive functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/551591/50776)

Comment: With the caveat that I'm not very familiar with the conventions of the subject, generally there is no notion of "eager/lazy evaluation" in this place of the mathematics. An equation is simply a proposition that two things are the same, not a prescription of how to do a "computation".

Comment: @Hurkyl Here eagerness is manifested in the domain of the resulting function, so as a partial function it makes a difference. The evaluation order $\mapsto^*$ was only for discussion purposes; I'm representing these purely as partial functions in the mathematical sense.

Comment: Usually, when writing some composite expression involving partial functions, one must make a decision about what to do about undefined subterms, and this is where "eagerness" comes in. For example, $\pi_2(\bot,0)$ is $\bot$ under eager semantics (the usual convention), and under lazy semantics $\pi_2(\bot,0)$ is $0$. There is no actual evaluation order here, but one expression is undefined and the other is defined so they are not $\simeq$ equivalent.

Comment: This actually manifests in ordinary algebra. "Sets and partial functions" turns out to be equivalent to "[Pointed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set) and homomorphisms". There are two distinct, relevant notions of product in the category of pointed sets: the cartesian product, in which you'd have $(\bot, 0) \neq (\bot, \bot)$, and the smash product in which you'd have $(\bot, 0) = (\bot, \bot)$. (in both cases, $(\bot, \bot)$ is the bottom element).

Comment: And, IIRC, it's the smash product, not the Cartesian product, that plays the natural role in the logic of functions. (e.g. currying/uncurrying)

Comment: There is an slight error in the linked question - we do not allow minimization to be applied to just any partial function, only to total functions. If we are allowed to apply minimization to partial computable functions, we end up with a class of functions larger than the class of partial computable functions. For example if we iterate $f(x) = \mu e. [ e \geq x \land \phi_e(0)\downarrow]$ we can enumerate the halting set $K$ in increasing order - no enumeration of that kind can be computable because $K$ is not computable.

Comment: @CarlMummert When using partial functions in the $\mu$ operator (which is not uncommon), $\mu n.\,[f(n)=0]$ is only said to be defined when there is a number $n$ satisfying $f(n)=0$ and also $f(m)$ is defined and nonzero at all $m<n$. That way it can be implemented as a naive sequential search on a Turing machine, and this does not enlarge the class.

Comment: Dear @CarlMummert I really do disagree with the fact that $\mu$ can only be used on total functions, otherwise it would not be recursive to know if a function is valid, as it is not recursive to know if a function is total.

Comment: @Xoff: indeed, but it there is no reason to expect that we know if a function is valid when written in that way. The way around this is to just write functions directly in the style of the normal form theorem - every definition written in that way is valid and every partial computable function can be written in that way.

Comment: @CarlMummert But let's say you have $f$ and $g$ on normal form. How can you compute the normal form of $\mu(f\circ g)$, if you can't even know if it's valid or not, because if it's not valid, it should probably be everywhere undefined, while if it is valid, it can be even total ! You're losing the fondamental recursiveness of $\mu$ and $\circ$ operators. The Gödel numbering rely ultimately on that. Every operations/compositions must lead to a valid function/program.

Comment: You can compute the index of the normal form of the composition uniformly from the indices of the two functions you are composing.  // But one standard version of the $\mu$ operator does always not lead to partial computable functions when applied to partial computable functions (I typed an example somewhere in this discussion) - although that same form of the $\mu$ operator works fine for the normal form theorem. That version of the $\mu$ operator is only effective when applied to total functions.

Comment: At the same time, for the other version of the $\mu$ operator - the one that is essentially just a while loop - we can again effectively compute an index of $\mu x.f$ from an index of $f$, of course.

Comment: @CarlMummert I'm sorry, I don't see myself as an expert, so i won't go on arguing, but explaining there are two different $\mu$ operators looks dangerously wrong to me. The one and only is a while loop, the other you are describing is just not computable. So I probably disagree with the spirit of your answer too, as the Kleene NF is a theorem not an axiom. Sorry 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many treatments of computability theory, primitive recursion is only applied to total functions, and then the $\mu$ operator is also only applied to total functions.  Composition is the only operation that needs to be applied to (potentially) partial functions.

This shows up in Kleene's normal form theorem: each partial computable function $f(\bar x)$ can be written in the form
$$
f(\bar x) \simeq U(\mu z. T(e,z,\bar x))
$$
for some fixed "index" $e$. Here both $T$ and $U$ are specific *total* primitive recursive functions, and the only possible way that $f$ could be partial is from the single application of the $\mu$ operator.

So, if $f$ and $g$ are partial computable, how do we find the normal form for the partial function $I(g,h,y,x)$ with
$$
I(g,h,y,x) \simeq \begin{cases} g(x) &  y = 0, \\ h(x) & y \not = 0.\end{cases}
$$

Start by letting $e_g$ be an index of $g$ and $e_h$ be an index of $h$.
Let $w(z,y,x) $ be the primitive recursive relation
$$
w(z,y,x) = \text{True} \leftrightarrow 
[ (
y = 0 \land T(e_g, z, x) ) \lor ( y \not = 0 \land T(e_h, z, x)]
$$
This function for $w$ is a *total* primitive recursive function. 
Let $e_w$ be the appropriate index for $w$. Then we have
$$
I(g,h,y,x) \simeq U(\mu z.T(e_w,z,y,x))
$$
as desired.  Here we do not need to worry about whether the definition of primitive recursion allows for lazy evaluation because we can build it into the index $e_w$.

Comment: Of course this same method can be used to make lazy projection functions and all other sorts of lazy functions - which is to say we can prove that if the lazy projection is applied to a pair of partial computable function then the desired reutling function is also partial computable.

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion - you need the normal form theorem to do "parallel computation", so that you can make internal sense of "lazy operations".

Comment: This answer can also be simplified a bit: Given indices $e_g$ and $e_h$, the function $E(x)=\begin{cases}e_g&x=0\\e_h&x\ne 0\end{cases}$ is primitive recursive (by the usual definition of ifz), and then $\phi(E(x),x)$ is the desired function, where $\phi(e,\bar x)\simeq U(\mu z.T(e,z,\bar x))$ is the universal pcf.

Answer (score 0):

$ifz(g,h)$ can be defined by

$\rho(g,h\circ(P^3_1))\circ(P^1_1,P^1_1)$

Note that evaluation strategy is not a problem here because $ifz$ need only to evaluate its input (is $x=0$ ?) and not the result of $g(0)$ or $h(x)$ to decide what it must do. But of course, if the strategy is not lazy, the case $x>0$ can be problematic. That's a good remark. I usually go with the lazy evaluation when I teach or simulate those functions. Note that the semantic is supposed to be lazy anyway : $P ^2_1(x_1,x_2)=x_1$ even if $x_2=\bot$.

Comment: With respect, this seems to be dodging the question. Do you have sources for evidence that lazy semantics is normally used here? Or is every textbook wrong? Personally, I am loath to adopt lazy semantics because it breaks the pairing function (you can't encode $(n,\bot)$ as a number in such a way that $L(n,\bot)=n$), which is important for cutting down on the parameter complexity.

Comment: I would say that in computability theory (the mathematical one, rather than computer science), $P^2_1$ is typically defined as a function from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. It does not make sense to evaluate it at $\bot$, but we don't treat $\bot$ as an actual value in any case, just a shorthand for some computation not halting.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro The pairing function must be seen as an actual computation that use both parameters (like the Cantor bijection), and so we have implicitly $\langle n,\bot\rangle=\bot$. But projection functions are another thing.

Comment: @CarlMummert But $ P^2_1\circ(0,\mu(S))$ is a valid mu-recursive function. So, if it doesn't make sense to evaluate this expression, you implies always an eager evaluation. I don't read that in the Kleene's definitions.

Comment: @Xoff: it makes sense to evaluate the latter because of the definition of generalized composition; that does not mean actually evaluating $P^2_1$ at the value $\bot$. In this case, because $\mu x.S(x)$ is never defined, $(0, \mu x.S(x))$ will also never be defined (its program won't halt unless it has a value for both arguments), and so $P^2_1 \circ (0, \mu x.S(x))$ is also never defined by the definition of generalized composition. But nevertheless $P^2_1 \circ (0, \mu x.S(x))$ is a partial computable function.